# Changing .gif Image of a picturebox stops animating new Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change image of a picturebox which is already a gif to another gif runtime . I use the code below but after changing the image , new gif loaded in picturebox doesn't animate and it stops at first frame :

```
public override void ChangeToEatingMode()
{
   this.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Images\Zombie A Attack.gif");
}
```

what is the problem with it ? and what is the solution ?

Comment: What happens if you try: `this.ImageLocation = @"..\..\Images\Zombie A Attack.gif";` instead?

Comment: still same problem :(

Comment: Are you running some lengthy background process or thread?

Comment: I call this method in a timer with special condition